# Alternative way of executing for loop in scala

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop, pattern-matching

Pattern matching in SCALA

I have 2 lists, one of which contains 20k elements and another contains 200k elements.
I am performing pattern matching where each of the list_1 elements are matched in list_2. I have written a FOR loop which gives me correct answers but it takes more than 2 hours for complete execution.

Is there any other alternative way to perform this task? How can I speed up the process?

The code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
var list_x = new ListBuffer[Int]();
var list_y = new ListBuffer[Int]();
for( a <- 1 to list_1.length-1){
    println(a);
    if(list_1(a).length > 4){               // if the string in a specific row contains > 4 characters
        val pat = list_1(a).replace("[","").replace("]","");
        val temp = list_2.map(x=> pat.r.findAllIn(x.toString).toList.length).indexOf(1);
        if(temp > 0){
            list_x+=a;
            list_y+=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.) I don't really know what lakhs is. , 2.) Give some example code to illustrate how the elements looks like and how you solved it for now. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask :)

Comment: @prateek can you please post your current code?

Comment: list_1 contains 20 thousand elements and list_2 contains 200 thousand elements.

Comment: Is matching "exactly" once a requirement? Is checking for one or more (1+) matches still acceptable?

Comment: It will identify as many matches as it can but in the end , I am taking the first match only.

Comment: If people even tell you that they don't understand Indian words, maybe you should have edited your question?

Answer (score 1):

Just a more scala-fashioned way to do that:

```scala
val findInList = for {
  (pat, index) <- list_1.zipWithIndex
  if pat.length > 4
  rexp = pat.replace("[","").replace("]","").r
  pos = list_2.indexWhere {
    rexp.findFirstIn(_).nonEmpty
  }
  if pos != -1
} yield (index, pos)

val (list_x, list_y) = findInList.unzip
```

Note: I'm assuming that matching at least one (1+) is acceptable, and that you need to not collect unmatched `pos != -1` instead of `!=0`.

Maybe we could improve this by knowing more about your data and eventually also choose a different `regexp` library.